Next js 14 with nx SSR/CSR issue
I am using Next.js 14 with an NX workspace to build a client-side application. In my app, I'm utilizing an authService from NX shared libs. However, I encounter an error related to SSR rendering, even though all my pages and layouts use the "use client" decorator.
Error:
Failed to get and set auth token: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at AuthService.logout (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/authentication/src/lib/authentication.ts:60:23)
    at AuthService.getValidToken (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/authentication/src/lib/authentication.ts:128:22)
    at async MetaDataProviderRepository.setAuthToken (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/meta-provider/src/lib/meta-data-provider/repositories/base-repository.ts:25:27)
    at async MetaDataProviderRepository.initializeAuthToken (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/meta-provider/src/lib/meta-data-provider/repositories/base-repository.ts:18:13)
Failed to get and set auth token: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at AuthService.logout (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/authentication/src/lib/authentication.ts:60:23)
    at AuthService.getValidToken (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/authentication/src/lib/authentication.ts:128:22)
    at async MetaDataProviderRepository.setAuthToken (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/meta-provider/src/lib/meta-data-provider/repositories/base-repository.ts:25:27)
    at async MetaDataProviderRepository.initializeAuthToken (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/../../libs/meta-provider/src/lib/meta-data-provider/repositories/base-repository.ts:18:13)

Code so far
AuthService in Libs:
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

interface Auth0DecodedHash {
  accessToken?: string;
  idToken?: string;
  expiresIn?: number;
}

export class AuthService {
  private static instance: AuthService;
  private auth0: auth0.WebAuth;
  private accessToken: string | null = null;
  private idToken: string | null = null;
  private expiresAt: number | null = null;

  private constructor(
    domain: string,
    clientId: string,
    redirectUri: string,
    audience: string,
    scope?: string,
  ) {
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: domain,
      clientID: clientId,
      redirectUri: redirectUri,
      responseType: 'token id_token',
      scope: scope,
      audience: audience,
    });

    this.accessToken = Cookies.get('accessToken') || null;
    this.idToken = Cookies.get('idToken') || null;
    const expiresAt = Cookies.get('expiresAt');
    this.expiresAt = expiresAt ? parseInt(expiresAt, 10) : null;
  }

  public static getInstance(): AuthService {
    if (!AuthService.instance) {
      AuthService.instance = new AuthService(
        process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_DOMAIN'] ?? '',
        process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'] ?? '',
        process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI'] ?? '',
        process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_AUDIENCE'] ?? '',
        process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_SCOPE'] ?? '',
      );
    }
    return AuthService.instance;
  }

  public login(): void {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }

  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult);
        window.location.replace('/');
      } else if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`);
      }
    });
  }

  private setSession(authResult: Auth0DecodedHash): void {
    const expiresIn = authResult.expiresIn || 0;
    this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken || null;
    this.idToken = authResult.idToken || null;
    this.expiresAt = expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime();

    Cookies.set('accessToken', this.accessToken ?? '');
    Cookies.set('idToken', this.idToken ?? '');
    Cookies.set('expiresAt', this.expiresAt.toString());
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.auth0.logout({
      returnTo: window.location.origin,
    });
    this.accessToken = null;
    this.idToken = null;
    this.expiresAt = null;
    Cookies.remove('accessToken');
    Cookies.remove('idToken');
    Cookies.remove('expiresAt');
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.expiresAt !== null && new Date().getTime() < this.expiresAt;
  }

  public getAccessToken(): string | null {
    if (!this.accessToken) {
      throw new Error('No access token found');
    }
    return this.accessToken;
  }

  public getIdToken(): string | null {
    if (!this.idToken) {
      throw new Error('No ID token found');
    }
    return this.idToken;
  }

  public getUserProfile(
    callback: (
      err: auth0.Auth0Error | null,
      profile: auth0.Auth0UserProfile | undefined,
    ) => void,
  ): void {
    if (!this.accessToken) {
      throw new Error('No access token found');
    }
    this.auth0.client.userInfo(this.accessToken, callback);
  }

  public checkSession(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
          this.setSession(authResult);
        }
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  public getUpdatedToken(): Promise<string | null> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
          this.setSession(authResult);
          resolve(authResult.accessToken);
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public async getValidToken(): Promise<string | null> {
    if (!this.isAuthenticated()) {
      try {
        const newToken = await this.getUpdatedToken();
        if (newToken) {
          return newToken;
        }
        this.logout();
        return null;
      } catch (error) {
        this.logout();
        return null;
      }
    }
    return this.getAccessToken();
  }
}

export const authService = AuthService.getInstance();

withAuth0 Wrapper function:
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { authService } from '@auth/lib';

export const withAuth0 = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  const ComponentWithAuth = (props: any) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(
      authService.isAuthenticated(),
    );
    const [user, setUser] = useState<auth0.Auth0UserProfile | null>(null);
    const [isClient, setIsClient] = React.useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
      setIsClient(true);
      if (window.location.hash) {
        authService.handleAuthentication();
      } else if (!isAuthenticated) {
        authService
          .checkSession()
          .then(() => {
            setIsAuthenticated(authService.isAuthenticated());
            if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
              authService.getUserProfile((err, profile) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                } else {
                  setUser(profile || null);
                }
              });
            } else {
              authService.login();
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            authService.login();
          });
      } else {
        authService.getUserProfile((err, profile) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            setUser(profile || null);
          }
        });
      }
    }, [isAuthenticated]);

    return isClient ? (
      !isAuthenticated ? (
        'Loading...'
      ) : (
        <WrappedComponent {...props} {...user} />
      )
    ) : null;
  };

  return ComponentWithAuth;
};

Root Layout:
import { Poppins } from 'next/font/google';
import '../globals.css';
import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';

const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
  variable: '--font-poppins',
  weight: ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900'],
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  console.log('SSR SSR 4');
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={poppins.className}> {children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

Layout wrapper:
'use client';
function Layout({ children }: Readonly<{ children: React.ReactNode }>) {

  return (
    <LayoutWrapper>
      <main className="bg-[#fafafa] h-screen flex flex-col">{children}</main>
    </LayoutWrapper>
  );
}

export default withAuth0(Layout);

Page:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import WorkspaceTemplate from '../../../ui-kit/templates/workspace-template';
import { ModalProvider } from '@shared/lib';
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ModalProvider>
        <WorkspaceTemplate />
        <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />
      </ModalProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

